# Разделение готового сайта

Tags: django

Имеется готовая CRM - в ней ведутся пользователи, клиенты, товары, продажи и т.п. - всё это по одной компании.
Есть задача - иметь возможность чтобы данным веб-приложением пользовались сразу несколько компаний - т.е. нужно разделить все данные так, чтобы компания видела только свои и могла менять только свои данные. При этом у администратора должа быть возможность быстро добавлять новые компании. Итоговое количество компаний будет измеряться сотнями.

Добавить во все модели company_id и связать пользователя с компанией - не проблема. Но что делать дальше? Как проще и надежнее организовать фильтрацию данных и контроль при сохранении? Крайне не хочется во все view прописывать фильтры и контролировать вручную, т.к. легко можно что-то забыть.

Comment: Что и как можно сделать зависит от текущей реализации. Но точно не надо переписывать текущие представления и модели. Нужно унаследовать от них классы, содержащие логику работы с компаниями.

Comment: Правильно заданный гуглу вопрос на этот счет - "django multitenancy". Решений масса, включая готовые. Выбираю подходящее себе

Comment: Почему бы просто не кастомизировать админку под каждую компанию?

Comment: Не понял, что имеется ввиду. Но компаний будет много, и не подразумевается кастомизация для каждой компании.